# Problema com threads no Android

Tags: android, okhttp

Estou tentando pegar valores de um `json` e jogar em um `recycleview` usando `OkHttp`, ele está pegando os valores e jogando na list, sem erros, porém não estou conseguindo passar esses valores para o adapter, a lista está chegando nula no `fragment`, tenho quase certeza que o problema é com a `thread`, provavelmente a thread principal está pegando o valor da lista antes da thread do `callback` setar...

Como solucionar?

Classe onde pego os valores do json: (creio que o problema é no método `sendGetRecipes`)

```
public class HttpRequest {

    private List<Recipes> recipesList;

    public void sendGetRecipes(String url) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                call.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                String strResponse = response.body().string();
                setRecipesList(strResponse);
                Log.d("HTTP", "PASSOU!!!!!");
                Log.d("HTTP", strResponse);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setRecipesList(String response) {
        recipesList = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Ingredients> ingredientsList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Steps> stepsList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (response != null) {
            try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Recipes recipes = new Recipes();
                    recipes.setId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
                    recipes.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    recipes.setImage(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                    recipes.setServings(jsonObject.getInt("servings"));

                    JSONArray ingrJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ingredients");
                    for (int j = 0; j < ingrJsonArray.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject ingrJsonObject = ingrJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        Ingredients ingredients = new Ingredients();
                        ingredients.setIngredient(ingrJsonObject.getString("ingredient"));
                        ingredients.setMeasure(ingrJsonObject.getString("measure"));
                        ingredients.setQuantity(ingrJsonObject.getInt("quantity"));

                        ingredientsList.add(ingredients);
                        //Log.d("ARRAY-JSON-INGR", ingrJsonObject.getString("ingredient"));

                    }

                    JSONArray stepsJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("steps");
                    for (int j = 0; j < stepsJsonArray.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject stepsJsonObject = stepsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        Steps steps = new Steps();
                        steps.setId(stepsJsonObject.getInt("id"));
                        steps.setDescription(stepsJsonObject.getString("description"));
                        steps.setShortDescription(stepsJsonObject.getString("shortDescription"));
                        steps.setVideoUrl(stepsJsonObject.getString("videoUrl"));
                        steps.setThumbnailUrl(stepsJsonObject.getString("thumbnailUrl"));

                        stepsList.add(steps);
                        //Log.d("ARRAY-JSON-INGR", ingrJsonObject.getString("ingredient"));

                    }

                    recipes.setIngredientsList(ingredientsList);
                    recipes.setStepsList(stepsList);

                    recipesList.add(recipes);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Recipes> getRecipesList() {
        return recipesList;
    }
}
```

Fragment (comentei no local onde ele tenta pegar a list)

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = MainFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView recipesRecycleView;
    private List<Recipes> recipesList;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        recipesRecycleView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recipesRecycleView);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recipesRecycleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
        httpRequest.setRecipesList(Recipes.RECIPES_URL);
        recipesList = httpRequest.getRecipesList();  // <------------- AQUI

        RecipesAdapter recipesAdapter = new RecipesAdapter(getActivity(), recipesList);
        recipesRecycleView.setAdapter(recipesAdapter);


        return view;
    }

}
```

Não postei o código do adapter pois o problema não é lá

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma interface na sua classe HttpRequest com um método de callback que vai trabalhar com a lista de receitas obtidas.

```
public interface OnRecipesReady {
    public void getRecipes(List<Recipes> recipes);
}
```

Cria um variável de handler para usar a interface nesta mesma classe e um construtor para receber uma referência do seu Fragment:

```
private OnRecipesReady handler;

public HttpRequest(OnRecipesReady h){
   handler = h;
}
```

No método setRecipesList() após o for e antes do catch, adicione essa linha:

```
handler.getRecipes(recipesList);
```

No seu Fragment implemente a interface e o método de callback e passe a criação do Adapter e associação na RecyclerView para o Adapter:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements OnRecipesReady {

 ...

   @Overide
   public void getRecipes(List<Recipes> recipes){
        recipesAdapter = new RecipesAdapter(getActivity(), recipes);
        recipesRecycleView.setAdapter(recipesAdapter); 
   }
}
```

Por fim, no OnCreateView altere a construção para:

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest(this);
```

corrija a inicialização do request chamando o método:

```
httpRequest.sendGetRecipes(Recipes.RECIPES_URL);
```

e remova todas as linhas seguintes até o "return view"

Comment: Não funcionou, mas talvez seja pq eu não entendi o que vc quis dizer...
não entendi o porque que você está chamando getRecipes dentro de setRecipesList

Comment: o getRecipes() é o callback da interface que eu criei. Coloquei dentro do setRecipesList, no final do método, para passar a lista de receitas gerada nomesmo para o handler que estiver implementando a interface, no caso o seu Fragment. A idéia é que seu Fragment aguarde a conclusão do sendGetRecipes e só atualize o adapter da lista quando a lista estiver pronta, o problema, analisando melhor o código agora, é que ele não está sendo chamado em lugar nenhum do código. Confundi o nome desse método com o setRecipesList. Vou dar uma olhada melhor no código mais tarde e edito minha resposta.

Comment: Com sua resposta aparece este erro "android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Comment: Pois é, como confundi o nome dos métodos e respondi na pressa, não vai funcionar mesmo. Mais tarde eu vejo com calma, pois estou no trabalho.

Comment: na verdade eu percebi isso e alterei o nome do método para getRecipesList, agora resolvi esse problema setando esse adapter na UIthread (runOnUiThread), ainda não entendi 100% do que você fez, meu java está realmente fraco, não sabia que dava para usar interface assim, e tb um pouco confuso com as threads no Android, mas estou dando uma lida aqui...
Atualiza sua resposta com o nome do método verdadeiro que eu aceito ela aqui

Comment: Cara, editei minha resposta, mas basicamente só estava faltando corrigir a chamada do httprequest trocando o nome do método. Todo o restante das sugestões que fiz acredito estarem corretas.